# Beginning Game Programming. Reference not resolved in Visual Studio 2012 (Lab 10)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, xna, xna-4.0

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Phone to follow this XNA course. The course is intended for XNA in Visual Studio 2010, but the professor said most people wouldn't have any problem in running other IDE configurations.

The project needs a custom library provided by the professor (ExplodingTeddies.dll). When running the project after adding this library to the references, I get the following error:

> The primary reference "ExplodingTeddies" could not be resolved because
>   it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
>   which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework.
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". To resolve this problem, either remove
>   the reference "ExplodingTeddies" or retarget your application to a
>   framework version which contains "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".

I don't know if it's because I'm using an Express edition or if it's because this is a XNA for Windows Phone project, but I can't retarget the application framework to any other option, so that's currently out of question.

Is there anything I can do, or do I have to wait for Dr. T to provide a modified library to use in VS 2012 Express?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The primary reference XXX could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106592/the-primary-reference-xxx-could-not-be-resolved-because-it-has-an-indirect-depe)

Comment: Sounds to me you've got the completely wrong version of Express, I see no indication that the course was intended to teach phone programming.  Use the desktop version, not the phone version.

Comment: Normally, there is no XNA framework available for VS 2012 for Desktop. There is a workaround, but it requires VS 2010 to be installed, and that just seems redundant. So far I solved this by using different assets (check the answer), but now I'll consider switching to VS 2010 to follow this course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I solved it out.

Instead of using the DLL for the Windows version, I downloaded the package for MonoDevelop. That zip file includes two .cs (Explosions.cs and TeddyBear.cs) files, which contain the required classes and spacename to make everything work.

If you're also using VS 2012 for this course, you'll still need to download the materials package for Windows to get the required graphic assets for the project.